# Defining a relation in Eloquent Model Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM users AS u INNER JOIN branches AS b ON u.branch_id = b.branch_id
```

This means to every one `user` there is a `branch` associated but one `branch` can be associated with many `user`.

Can anyone help me how to define this relation?

I did this

I wrote this relation in User model

```
public function branch()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Branch');
}
```

And it returns null.

Comment: You're going against the naming conventions. Laravel can handle that but you're generally going to have a bad time. The identifier field in your `branch` table should be just `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem seems to be inverse of one to many relationship i.e. Many to One.

Here, in your case Many Users belongs to one Branch. So, you can define Many to One relationship in `User` model as :

```
public function branch()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Branch','branch_id');
}
```

Now, you can access branch of a user like this:

```
$user = User::find($id);

$branch = $user->branch;
```

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
public function branch()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Branch','branch_id');
}
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: This helps, can  you please explain it. I am learning eloquent.

Comment: @Alen Please follow this link (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)